# UDPClient only receives one datagram

Tags: c#, udp

I'm trying to read continuous UDP bytes (or at least more than 1 at a time). My buffer is 4 x the size of a single datagram/packet (1000 bytes).

```
 Byte[] receiveBytes = new Byte[4096];

 UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient(56885);
 IPEndPoint RemoteIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
 Byte[] receiveBytes = udpClient.Receive(ref RemoteIpEndPoint);
```

Comment: How much data are you sending? What rate are you sending it at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Receive` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive.aspx) will only read *one* datagram packet at a time. If you want to read multiple datagrams, you need to call `Receive` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to receive multiple packets, you should consider using an asynchronous method to receive them.  The UdpClient class has an asynchronous idiom where you give it a callback function and move on to do other processing (such as updating the UI).

[Here is an example from the source:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.beginreceive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
public static bool messageReceived = false;

public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
  UdpClient u = (UdpClient)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).u;
  IPEndPoint e = (IPEndPoint)((UdpState)(ar.AsyncState)).e;

  Byte[] receiveBytes = u.EndReceive(ar, ref e);
  string receiveString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

  Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", receiveString);
  messageReceived = true;
}

public static void ReceiveMessages()
{
  // Receive a message and write it to the console.
  IPEndPoint e = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
  UdpClient u = new UdpClient(e);

  UdpState s = new UdpState();
  s.e = e;
  s.u = u;

  Console.WriteLine("listening for messages");
  u.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), s);

  // Do some work while we wait for a message. For this example, 
  // we'll just sleep 
  while (!messageReceived)
  {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
  }
}
```